# What is the Apache spark.sql.types.DataTypes of java.time.LocalDate

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-time

I develop the java pojo class which contains java.time.LocalDate member variable `date`.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EntityMySQL implements Serializable {
    
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDate date;
    
    private float value;
    
    private String id;
    
    private String title;

    private static StructType structType = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
              
              DataTypes.createStructField("date", DataTypes.DateType, false),  // this line throws Exception
              DataTypes.createStructField("value", DataTypes.FloatType, false),
              DataTypes.createStructField("id", DataTypes.StringType, false),
              DataTypes.createStructField("title", DataTypes.StringType, false)
    });
```

As you see, the "date" member variable type is `java.time.LocalDate`. But in static structType variable,
I set the type of `date` to `DateTypes.DateType`. When I bind the pojo class with spark data frame. it throws the error like below,

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.time.LocalDate is not a valid external type for schema of date
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.StaticInvoke_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.writeFields_0_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$Serializer.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:210)
```

When I set the date member variable to `java.util.Date`, the spark `DataTypes.DateType` is the correct configuration and there are no errors. But In case of using `java.time.LocalDate`, the codes does not work correctly and throws exceptions. If I have to generate custom Date type, kindly inform me how. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java.time.LocalDate is not supported up to Spark even if you  try to write an Encoder for the java Date type it will not work.

I advise you to convert java.time.LocalDate to some other supported type like java.sql.Timestamp or java.sql.Date  or epoch or date-time in string.